# My PHP code not creating a directory

Tags: php, directory

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$title='New Account'; /*This is a page that creates new account*/
include('header.php'); /*header file included*/
extract($_POST);
if(isset($r9))   /*$r9 is submit */
{   
    if(!empty($r1) && !empty($r2) && !empty($r3) && !empty($r4) && !empty($r5) && !empty($r6) && !empty($r7) && !empty($r8) )
    {
        if(is_dir("user/$r3"))   //$r3 is the email the person is providing
        {
            echo "User already registered";
        }
        else
        {
            mkdir("user/$r3");   /*directory creation*/
            file_put_contents("user/$r3/details.txt","$r1\n$r2\n$r4\n$r5\n$r6\n$r7\n$r8");
            header("location:welcome.php");    /*the next page it must go after this*/
        }
    }

}
?>
```

This is my PHP code and it is not creating the directory. Please help me out.

Comment: Why switch off error reporting when attempting to debug something?!

Comment: Hi, Sonal, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: What is the result of mkdir? True or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please turn on the error reporting to see the error messages, that will help you to solve this problem. Please check if your web server has permissions to creating a new directory. If your web server has the permissions already to write in the folder *user* then try to edit the following code:

```
mkdir("user/$r3");
```

to

```
mkdir("/THE_HOLE_URL_TO_THIS_FOLDER/user/$r3");
```

*for example mkdir("/opt/lampp/htdocs/myhomespace/user/$r3");*

Comment: The error reporting and some echo statements to check where the error is helped. Thank you.